# How to animate line in scatter plot using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, scatter

Consider official example for scatter plot animation

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
```

this results in a plot in which markers are getting animated. However, I want to animate the connecting lines too which is not directly possible. I tried to update `mode` and `marker` properties for the `frames` like `fig.frames.data[n].mode=markers+lines` but still no luck. Could someone let me know where I am going wrong.

Cheers,
DD

Answer (score 1):

If you by `animate the connecting lines` means connecting, for example, all markers illustrating `Asia` etc in the example above, then adding the following to your code will produce the plot below.

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(mode = 'lines+markers'))
for fr in fig.frames:
    for d in fr.data:
        d.update(mode='markers+lines')
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90],
           # mode = 'markers+lines'
           height = 600, width = 1000
          )

# lineas and markers on first display
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(mode = 'lines+markers'))

# lineas and markers on animation frames
for fr in fig.frames:
    for d in fr.data:
        d.update(mode='markers+lines')
        
fig.show()
```