# Plotly: scatterplot and animated line plot in the same figure

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I need to create a scatterplot in plotly, and overlay a line plot on top of it. I found that I can do it if I create the figure using graph objects, and then add the data using plotly express:

```
scatter = px.scatter(...)
line = px.line(...)
fig = go.Figure(data=scatter.data + line.data)
```

But the problem is that I need to animate the line plot with a slider, and when I use the graph_objects interface I can't do it.

Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060711/how-to-animate-line-in-scatter-plot-using-plotly-express

Comment: The data from the scatter plot and line plot and line plot are independent. I need to animate the line plot while keeping the scatter plot fixed.

Answer (score 3):

- have simulated two *independent* data sets (dimensionality of axes and animation is consistent)
- it's not clear if you want to integrate two animated figures or an animated and fixed figure.  Have used former, later would be same just traces from fixed figure would be copied into each target frame
- it's all about being consistent

  1. integrate the traces
  2. integrate the frames
  3. pick a layout

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

r = np.random.RandomState(22)

# simulate two independent dataframes.  NB some consistency for axes and animation
df_line = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "animation": np.repeat(list("ABCDE"), 10),
        "x": np.tile(np.linspace(0, 10, 10), 5),
        "y": r.uniform(0, 10, 50),
    }
)

df_scatter = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "animation": np.repeat(list("ABCDE"), 50),
        "x": np.tile(np.linspace(0, 10, 50), 5),
        "y": r.uniform(0, 10, 250),
    }
)

line = px.line(df_line, x="x", y="y", animation_frame="animation")
scatter = px.scatter(df_scatter, x="x", y="y", animation_frame="animation")

# now integrate, traces, frames and layout
fig = go.Figure(
    data=line.data + scatter.data,
    frames=[
        go.Frame(data=fr1.data + fr2.data, name=fr1.name)
        for fr1, fr2 in zip(line.frames, scatter.frames)
    ],
    layout=scatter.layout,
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Great contribution! I've spent quite some time today trying to get a similar approach working, so I'm really glad you came up with this

Comment: thanks @vestland BTW recently coded this answer that makes an animated gif easy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460434/how-to-export-save-an-animated-bubble-chart-made-with-plotly/73788157#73788157

Answer (score 1):

I see you've used `px.line` in your example, so I'd just like to add that you can easily build a figure with `Plotly Express` with animations and include a fixed trace by simply using:

```
fig.add_trace()
```

Below an example that uses the `gapminder` dataset. For your use-case, if you've set it up with `px.line`, you should easily be able to make the switch between which traces are animated; the scatter or the line.

#### Figure

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           # size="pop",
                 color="continent", hover_name="country",
           # log_x=True,
                 size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90],
           # mode = 'markers+lines'
           height = 600, width = 1000
          )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 10000, 20000, 30000], y = [40,50,60, 70], mode = 'lines'))

fig.show()
```